# Laravel route not defined error when route is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my view I am calling the following function:

```
<a href="{!! Route('admin.sessions') !!}">Sessions</a>
```

Which is triggering the following error:

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
Route [admin.sessions] not defined.
```

The thing is in my routes I have the following:

```
Route::get('admin/sessions', ['middleware' => ['ability:super_admin,sessions.view'], 'uses' => 'Admin\SessionsController@index', 'as' => 'admin.sessions']);
```

Am I missing something? This should work shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem I had another route that was referencing the same URL but with a different name.